# Kestrel application uses system certificates?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, https, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to deploy an Asp.net core 3.1 application on Windows Server. However, it gets the exception when specifying the https port.

```
PS C:\Websites\Portal> .\Blazor.exe --urls https://localhost:5001
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the defau
lt developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run
'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configure
Options)
```

I tried to run

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

but no luck. (The .Net core on the server is still 3.0. Maybe this is the reason?)

Is it a way to use an existing certificates (e.g. from IIS installed) for Kestrel application?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Plus, when doing `dotnet dev-certs https`, I get `A valid HTTPS certificate with a key accessible across security partitions was not found. The following command will run to fix it: 'sudo security set-key-partition-list -D localhost -S unsigned:,teamid:UBF8T346G9'`